# Hibernate: Add column in subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

Is there possibility to add new column in subclass of entity? Something like:

Base class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Column
    private String login;
}
```

Subclass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserWithField extends User {
    @Column
    private String field;
}
```

I don't want to change base class (User) at all. Would it work somehow?

Comment: It's not a good practice but you can add

Comment: So what would be a good practice when i want to add column to base class table without editing base class?

Comment: Is this solved your doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create new class for new entity. Generally,In hibernate inheritance is used when you have two or more related tables.

Comment: That's the same solution, which I'm using right now. If no one will post better looking solution i will accept your answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: Ok. But I'm telling you not to extend User class, create UserWithField as separate class having all fields from User class and extra fields of UserWithField class

Comment: Yes - thats what i'm using right now. Just want to know is there any better solution :)

Comment: I don't think there is any alternative. Just wait for some time if any one has  it.It will be helpful for me as well

Comment: @Abhijeet I have a base class A, Class B extends A and Class C extends B. Using discriminator, I'm able to add the properties and association of Class C in table A. Is it possible to add the props & associations in table B ?